# How can I configure "mousekeys"?

Tags: 11.10, unity, keyboard, unity-2d, accessibility

Under 11.04, the option to control the pointer with the numpad was set in the Hardware/Keyboard settings page.

How can I turn on mousekeys or configure them in newer releases?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In 11.10 and above you go to **System Settings** in the Power cog menu and select **Universal Access**.

[image]

Under the **Pointing and clicking** tab you will see a slider that lets you turn Mouse Keys on and off. The label says: Control the pointer using the keypad.

[image]

Comment: How do I configure it further? It only moves one pixel at a time when I press the arrows.

Answer (score 3):

grahammechanical's answer is good, but I want to talk about some extra features as I've dreamed to be a "keyboard geek" which turned out to be too extreme:

1.Killing mice, one at a time(replace mouse keys)

xdotool - command-line X11 automation tool（+keyborad custom shortcuts）

```
xdotool click 3（context menu）
xdotool click 2（middle）
xdotool click 1（left click）
```

2.replace mouse movement(use keyboard to move mouse pointer more accurate - need the support of "universal access -> Mouse Keys")

xkbset - user preference utility for XKB extensions for X

ma - mousekeysaccel

```
-xkbset ma 60 10 10 5 2
xkbset ma 60 10 10 20 10
```

Answer (score 1):

This procedure is the same from 11.10 to at least 14.04, and it is nicely documented on [help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/).   Because those instructions have been kept up to date, it's likely that the documentation will also be extremely helpful for future versions of Ubuntu.

Here are the links for mousekeys in versions 12.04 through 14.04 -- note that the url is identical with the exception of the version number:

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html 
[...] 
 https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html

Here are the [**12.04**-based instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html) from the help site.

1. Click the icon at the very right of the menu bar and select `System Settings`.
2. Click `Universal Access`.
3. Select the `Pointing and Clicking` tab.
4. Switch `Mouse Keys` on.
5. Make sure that <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is turned off. You will now be able to move the mouse pointer using the keypad.

For Unity, I found it easier to hit the <kbd>Super</kbd>, type in the first few letters of "universal", then skip to the third step given above ("Select the Pointing and Clicking tab").

This is reflected in the [**14.04** **documentation**](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/mouse-mousekeys.html):

1. Tap the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to open the Dash.
2. Type `Universal Access` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the Universal Access settings.
3. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> once to select the `Seeing` tab.
4. Press ← once to switch to the `Pointing and Clicking` tab.
5. Press ↓ once to select the `Mouse Keys` switch then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to switch it on.
6. Make sure that <kbd>Num Lock</kbd> is turned off. You will now be able to move the mouse pointer using the keypad.

Comment: How do I configure mouse keys once it's enabled? It only moves 1 pixel at a time, I'd like it to move faster.

Answer (score 1):

In case "xkbset ma 20 10 10 10 10" doesn't work for you and gives you the error message "XKB not supported for display :0".

Then, you can use the following command in your terminal to configure the speed of your mouse:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
dconf-editor
```

In the "dconf-editor" window, navigate to "org" > "gnome" > "desktop" > "a11y" > "keyboard" using the sidebar on the left. Click on the "mousekeys-max-speed" key to select it. In the right pane, click on the "Use default value" toggle switch to turn it off. Next, adjust the slider to set the maximum speed you want for your mouse movement.

After following these steps, the mouse movement speed should be adjusted to your desired settings when using Mouse Keys in Ubuntu's accessibility features.