# mouse keys settings in 12.04?

Tags: mouse, configuration, settings, accessibility

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I configure “mousekeys”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68807/how-can-i-configure-mousekeys)

Where have the settings for mouse keys such as "acceleration" that used to be present in older versions gone to? Is there a config file where I could edit this manually?

The pointer is moving much more slowly than I'd like, so I need to know how to adjust it.

Comment: Settings should all be under "mouse" and "universal" settings -- if they're not working as expected, this should probably be reported as a bug.