# Polkit not accepting my credentials

Tags: policykit

I am having trouble authenticating via policy kit. Sudo works just fine.

In reference to this [previous question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333143/authenticate-in-ubuntu/333171), here is my output of

```
$ ps aux | grep [p]olkit
pkcheck --action-id org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set --allow-user-interaction --process $(pidof -s bash)
```

here (I have replaced my personal information with stars):

```
$ ps aux | grep [p]olkit
root      1003  0.0  0.0 286500  6824 ?        Sl   Oct21   1:04 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
********  4685  0.0  0.0 651540 17792 ?        Sl   09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1
$ pkcheck --action-id org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set --allow-user-interaction --process $(pidof -s bash)
Error checking for authorization org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Error.Failed: Action org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set is not registered
```

Any information on resolving this would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Action org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set is not registered`! may be you are missing the `.policy` file declaring this polkit action

Your command works fine in machine (Ubuntu 16.04), let's track it:

```
~$ pkcheck --action-id org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set --allow-user-interaction --process $(pidof -s bash)
polkit\56retains_authorization_after_challenge=true
polkit\56temporary_authorization_id=tmpauthz1

~$ grep -r "org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set" /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/
/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.SystemToolsBackends.policy:  <action id="org.freedesktop.systemtoolsbackends.set">

~$ dpkg -S /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.SystemToolsBackends.policy
system-tools-backends: /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.SystemToolsBackends.policy
```

To confirm the issue check if you have it installed using `apt-cache policy system-tools-backends`

To fix it try reinstalling its package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall system-tools-backends
```